# How can i move a video element without restart?

Tags: html, css

Can i move video element without restarting the video. I've tried sevaral ways without any success. Any ideas. Maybe some hacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible. I've tried a little bit with javascript as well. No solution.
Please look also [is-it-possible-to-move-a-video-element-in-the-dom-without-resetting-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502886/is-it-possible-to-move-a-video-element-in-the-dom-without-resetting-it)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will help you:
[HTML5 Dynamic Video Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602525/html5-video-player-dynamically-loading-videos)

You just have to adjust this loading with a buffering....maybe it'll work

But maybe you could tell us what exactly you want to do this sounds interesting :)